# filter by a measure in dax

Tags: ssas, dax, tabular

Please help, how can I rewrite this dax measure? this works very slowly. I need to calculate one measure - [mValue 2 period] and filter by the other measure.

```
mNew launches Value:= 
    CALCULATE(
        [mValue 2 period],
        FILTER('UniqueSKUs', [mValue 1 period] = 0))
    
MEASURE [mValue 1 period] =  CALCULATE(
    [mValue],
    ALL('Date 2 Period'[Year]),
    ALL('Date 2 Period'[MonthName]), 
    ALL('Date 2 Period'[YearMonthName])
)

MEASURE Facts[mValue 2 period] =  CALCULATE(
    'Facts'[mValue],
    ALL('Date'[Year]),
    ALL('Date'[MonthName]), 
    ALL('Date'[YearMonthName])
)

MEASURE [mValue] = ROUND(SUM([Amount]),0)
```

The part of scheme SSAS Tabulal Cube:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggjqo.jpg)

Comment: what's the code for [mValue 2 period] measure? And what is your data model? (a diagram would be helpful)

Comment: I'm a bit unsure what the end goal is with these calculations. Are both the Date and the Date 2 Period tables related to Facts on the DateBegin column? Are you adding two tables to the model to give users the ability to arbitrarily select two dates and calculate the SUM(Amount) in Period 2 for the products only bought in  Period 1?

Comment: @MartinMason, Yes, that's right. we need to see how much money we have earned by introducing new products - SKUs. the main slowdown starts when this measure is added to the matrix element (power bi) with the drill-down to the marketplaces, for example (other  reference related to the fact table, like the SKU reference).